# Rails migration script from SQL create table script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a SQL script to create a new table "Product" in my database.

Is there a way I can generate the Rails migration script to create this table using the SQL script?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `execute`:

```
class CreateMyTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE SQL-STATEMENTS-GO-HERE
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      DROP SQL-STATEMENTS-GO-HERE
    SQL
  end
end
```

Comment: When `db/schema.rb` is generated will schema from tables created this way be correctly included?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  It's generated using a database dump.  But it might not be a perfect representation.  See this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you

Comment: @Jordan: Not necessarily. If your schema contains things that ActiveRecord doesn't understand (such as real foreign keys, CHECK constraints, or anything else that isn't baby-talk DDL) then `schema.rb` will leave it out. If you switch to `structure.sql` then you'll get a raw database dump that will contain everything.